# Adding Navigation property breaks breeze client-side mappings (but not Server Side EF6)

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I have an application that I developed standalone and now am trying to integrate into a much larger model.  Currently, on the server side, there are 11 tables and an average of three navigation properties per table.  This is working well and stable.

The larger model has 55 entities and 180+ relationships and includes most of my model (less the relationships to tables in the larger model).  Once integrated, a very strange thing happens: the server sends the same data, the same number of entities are returned, but the exportEntities function returns a string of about 150KB (rather than the 1.48 MB it was returning before) and all queries show a tenth of the data they were showing before.

I followed the troubleshooting information on the Breeze website.  I looked through the Breeze metadata and the entities and relationships seem defined correctly.  I looked at the data that was returned and 9 out of ten entities did not appear as an object, but as a function: `function (){return e.refMap[t]}` which, when I expand it, has an 'arguments' property: `Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them`.

For reference, here are the two entities involved in the breaking change.

The Repayments Entity

```
public class Repayment
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int DistrictId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int RepaymentId { get; set; }

    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    public int SeasonId { get; set; }

     ...

    #region Navigation Properties

    [InverseProperty("Repayments")]
    [ForeignKey("DistrictId")]
    public virtual District District { get; set; }


    // The three lines below are the lines I added to break the results
    //  If I remove them again, the results are correct again
    [InverseProperty("Repayments")]
    [ForeignKey("DistrictId,ClientId")]
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Repayments")]
    [ForeignKey("DistrictId,SeasonId,ClientId")]
    public virtual SeasonClient SeasonClient { get; set; }
```

The Client Entity

```
public class Client : IClient
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int DistrictId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    ....

    // This Line lines were in the original (working) model
    [InverseProperty("Client")]
    public virtual ICollection<Repayment> Repayments { get; set; }

    ....
}
```

The relationship that I restored was simply the inverse of a relationship that was already there, which is one of the really weird things about it.  I'm sure I'm doing something terribly wrong, but I'm not even sure at this point what information might be helpful in debugging this.

For defining foreign keys and inverse properties, I assume I must use either data annotations or the FluentAPI even if the tables follow all the EF conventions.  Is either one better than the other?  Is it necessary to consistently choose one approach and stay with it?  Does the error above provide any insight as to what I might be doing wrong?  Is there any other information I could post that might be helpful?

Breeze is an excellent framework and has the potential to really increase our reach providing assistance to small farmers in rural East Africa, and I'd love to get this prototype working.

THanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, some of what you are describing can be explained by breeze's default behavior of compressing the payload of any query results that return multiple instances of the same entity. If you are using something like the default 'json.net' assembly for serialization, then each entity is sent with an extra '$id' property and if the same entity is seen again it gets serialized via a simple '$ref' property with the value of the previously mentioned '$id'.

On the breeze client during deserialization these '$refs' get resolved back into full entities.  However, because the order in which deserialization is performed may not be the same as the order that serialization might have been performed, breeze internally creates deferred closure functions ( with no arguments) that allow for the deferred resolution of the compressed results regardless of the order of serialization.  This is the

```
function (){return e.refMap[t]}
```

that you are seeing.

If you are seeing this value as part of the actual top level query result, then we have a bug, but if you are seeing this value while debugging the results returned from your server, before they have been returned to the calling function, then this is completely expected ( especially if you are viewing the contents of the closure before it should be executed.)

So a couple of questions and suggestions

- Are you are actually seeing an error processing the result of your query or are simply surprised that the results are so small?  If it's just a size issue, check and see if you can identify data that should have been sent to the client and is missing. It is possible that the reference compression is simply very effective in your case.
- take a look at the 'raw' data returned from your web service. It should look something like this, with '$id' and '$ref' properties.

  ```
  [{
    '$id': '1',
    'Name': 'James',
    'BirthDate': '1983-03-08T00:00Z',
   },
   {
    '$ref': '1'
  }]
  ```

  if so, then look at the data and make sure that an '$'id' exists that correspond to each of your '$refs'.  If not, something is wrong with your server side serialization code. If the data does not look like this, then please post back with a small example of what the 'raw' data does look like.

Comment: THanks!  That is really helpful. So I have re-run the query in its working and non-working states.  I page the data (100/page), so the last page only has 40 Top-Level entities.  In the Raw Data, I see the $id in each object (or the object replaced with a $ref) for each object instance throughout the Entity Stack, just like I would expect a cyclic JSO to serialize.  I'm still trying to format some of the data, but it looks like the $Refs and $ids are exactly the same whether the final results are correct or not (More on that when I've had a chance to parse it more), BUT...

Comment: ...IN the first query (the broken one), the data returned to the success function is missing 90% of the entities.  All of the entities that exist in the returned data have ids in the double digits in the raw data (the largest $ref I see is around 785, I have not found and entities in the returned data corresponding to a ref of greater than 60).  I suspect there is an entity somewhere in the stack that cannot be deserialized by Breeze and the deserialization process is aborted.  I'll keep digging and let you know what I find.  Any thoughts about other avenues of investigation?

Comment: Are you using Json.Net? If so have you changed any of its configuration parameters?

Comment: I believe so.  I have made no changes to the configuration and am using the default JSON serializer/deserializer for the Breeze Server webapi2.2 for EF6 on the server, installed by nuget.  Again on the client side I have added no scripts to serialize/deserialize the JSON.  THat should all be the default nuget installation.

Comment: CORRECTION: it looks like the nuget install uses newtonsoft.JSON.  Does that make sense?  I don't see a reference to JSON.NET in the project.

Comment: Json.net is NewtonSoft, so you are ok there. Can you create a very small query that causes incorrect results? and post just the formatted json being returned from the server. i.e json with '$id' and '$ref' tags that doesn't seem to deserialize properly.

Comment: That's an excellent idea.  I'll certainly try. Its almost midnight here and everyone's asleep, but I'll get to that first thing in the morning. Each page is deserialized individually, correct? So o could possibly just change the page size if other methods don't work?  Thanls

Comment: Try using [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QBADOq9TG3nFIay26OBY?p=preview) to reproduce the problem.  

    1. Get the metadata and the query results from the data moving over the wire (using the Network tab of your browser's developer tools).  
    2. Replace the metadata in `metadata.js` with yours.
    3. Replace the query results in `queryResults.js` with yours.
    4. Change the `index.html` (line 13) to show some property of your entity.  
See if this helps demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @Steve, Thanks!  That's great, I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: @JayTraband, I have created a [Gist (here at github)](https://gist.github.com/beartums/b2191b23497a60df3af4) that gives some information.  In is you will find 3 files: the 1st 10 toplevel entities returned by the broken version, the same for the working version, and the client-side metadata (from metadataStore.exportMetadata()) for the broken version (which is, byte for byte, exactly the same as the client metadata for the working version, at least according to my notepad+ compare plugin).

Comment: @SteveSchmitt, I finally got around to using that plunker tonight.  Using the first ten entities returned and the metadata from /breeze/.../metadata.  It worked fine.  In the data returned to the success function, only the 1st 4 entities are present (and most descendent entities are NOT present in those).  In the plunker, all the entities and their descendant entities are fully populated and correct.  Is that what would be expected based on Jay's post above?  Does that tell me the server-side metadata is correct, but Breeze is having a problem with it?  I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: @Beartums, I used Steve's plunker to determine the problem I documented below. This is likely NOT a breeze issue.

Comment: @JayTraband, thanks for the clarification.  I'll keep looking.  I'm assuming the best place to look is in the metadata provided by EF6 (since queries from C# are working correctly).  Does that seem to be about right to you?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your Gist, I think I see the issue. Your metadata is out of sync with the actual results returned by your query. In particular, if you look for the '$id' value of "17" in your actual results you'll notice that it is first found in the 'Client' property of the 'Repayment' type, but your metadata doesn't have 'Client' navigation property defined for the 'Repayment' type ( there is a 'ClientId' ). My guess is that you are reusing an 'older' version of your metadata.

The reason that this results in incomplete results is that once breeze determines that it is deserializing an 'entity' ( i.e. a json object that has $type property that maps to an actual entityType), it only attempts to deserialize the 'known' properties of this type, i.e. those found in the metadata.  In your case, the 'Client' navigation property on the 'Repayment' type was never being deserialized, and any refs to the '$id' defined there are therefore not available.

Comment: Thanks!  Now I know what's happening on the client side, at least.  I guess that leads to the question: Is there any way to track down why this is happening?  I have leaned toward using Data Annotations to describe the relationships, but there are also some FluentApi specifications.  Would that tend to be a problem?  I can look through the Server Metadata to see if the same problem is present, but if it is, is there anything I can do about it?  Is the server metadata prepared and served by EF or Breeze?  Any thoughts about where I should look?

Comment: Some further thoughts (Sorry to bombard you like this): Why would it be reusing the old metadata?  I'm not caching anything and I'm refreshing the page between connections -- the JS is updating when I do it.  Lastly (for now) it occurs to me that there are 55 entities in this metadata and I'm only currently using 11.  THose 11 are fully annotated with data annotations.  The other 44 are haphazardly anotated with data annotations and FluentAPI, but only as much as EF6 needs.  Could something in those other entities be breaking the relationships i need?  Should i annotate them all?

Comment: Without more detail ( please don't see all 55) it's hard to tell. I would make sure that the server side metadata code is actually executing when you restart the server. If not, it is possible that your client is caching a previous metadata fetch request.

Comment: Thanks for that thought.  I just checked it out and the server is definitely not caching the metadata.  The metadata from the server for the two configurations is different -- not by a lot, but in about six places (maybe 100 lines total out of 9400 when formatted for readability).  The differences appear reasonable, but I'm not sure what I'm looking at.