# Breeze not loading all data into entities

Tags: breeze

I am having an issue where not all data that is being sent from the server is being loaded into the entities. I request an array of objects that contain another array of objects and when I examine the request I can see that all of the expected data is their. However, when it is serialized into the javascript objects the child array only contains one of the three items that was sent from the server.

What's even more odd is that for me it is always the same parent objects that are missing data in their child array but if someone else goes in then they have completely different parent objects that are missing data in their child arrays, but the items that were missing for me are there for them.

I am not really looking for coding help here, I just want to know if anyone else has experienced anything like this before and how they may have resolved it or if anyone might know of any possible causes for this behavior.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@JCherryHomes, Yeah!  OMG, that is frustrating!  Our first application had this problem regularly.  Most of the time I was able to eliminate it by simplifying the data model (our context was and is our entire database).  That wasn't a long term solution, but it did get the problem down to a reverse navigation property on a single (apparently not directly related) table.

Eventually I moved as much definition (foreign keys, relationships, etc) into the context and out of data annotations and we got it working.  Haven't had a problem since.  But I'm not sure if what I did fixed it or if some other aspect of the fooling around worked.

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27906479/adding-navigation-property-breaks-breeze-client-side-mappings-but-not-server-si) got some clues, but didn't lead me to an answer (my fault, I'm sure).  Maybe some of the responses from Jay will help you.

Good Luck